# Number of sequences in A, B, and C, where number of A's is even and number of B's is odd.

Tags: combinatorics

Given three letters A,B and C. Find number of words of length 11 in which A occurs even number of times and B occurs odd number of times.

( Caution: A can occur 0 number of times and there is no restriction on C )

My Try: I tried making cases but it doesn't work as there will be more than $50$ cases.

Is there any mechanism to solve this?

Even a trinomial expansion won't work as again we have to find possibilities for $n+m+l = 11$ with n even and m odd.

Comment: Are you familiar with generating functions?  It seems to me that you want the coefficient of $x^{11}$ for the generating function $(1 + x^2 + x^4 + x^6 + \cdots)(x + x^3 + x^5 + x^7 + \cdots)(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + \cdots)$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig That would count the words up to permutation, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Christoph  Yes, you are correct.  Perhaps the way to go is with a recurrence relation.

Comment: An exponential generating function should work. $$(1 + (1/2!)x^2 + (1/4!)x^4 + \dots)(x + (1/3!)x^3 + (1/5!)x^5+\dots)(1+x+(1/2!)x^2+(1/3!)x^3+\dots)$$ You want $11!$ times the coefficient of $x^{11}$.

Answer (score 1):

If there were $n$ letters, the number of valid sequences would be $(3^n-(-1)^n)/4$.

To prove this, call a sequence valid if it satisfies your given conditions, and call a sequence *partially valid* if the number of occurrences of "A" or "B" is odd. There are two steps:

1. The number of partially valid sequences is $(3^n-(-1)^n)/2$. To see this, we will divide the set of $3^n$ sequences into pairs, where one sequence in each pair is valid. Namely, the mate of a given sequence is found by changing the first occurrence of "A" or "C" into the other letter, "C" or "A". This pairs up almost all sequences; the only one unpaired is the sequence of all "B"s. This is valid if and only if $n$ is odd. Therefore,
   $$
   \text{# partially valid sequences}=
   \begin{cases}
   (3^n-1)/2 & n \text{ is even}
   \\
   (3^n-1)/2+1 & n \text{ is odd}
   \end{cases}
   $$
   This works out to be the same as $(3^n-(-1)^n)/2$.
2. Exactly half of the partially valid sequences are valid. A similar method works; given a partially valid sequence, you can change whether or not it is valid by changing the first instance of "A" or "B" to the other letter, "B" or "A".

---

The matching, or pairing, I described in both steps is often referred to as a sign reversing involution.

Let me finish by saying that I think the best way to do this problem is to use EGF's, as awkward suggested in a comment. When you do so, a very simple formula falls out, which motivated me to look for this combinatorial proof. That is, I did not pull this out of thin air.

Comment: If we consider a sequence: AAAABBBBCCC, not valid. Replacing first occurrence of A by C: CAAABBBBCCC These two sequences will form a pair but none of them is valid. Correct me if wrong

Comment: I only claimed that one of the pair is “partially valid”. Indeed, the second sequence has 3 A’s and 4 B’s, and 3 + 4 = 7, and 7 is odd. You then divide all the partially valid sequences into pairs where exactly one in each pair of valid. The second sequence is paired with CBAABBBBCCC (change first A to B), which is valid.